# Jasmine - Can't scroll window by executeScript anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm usually used the command below:

```
browser.driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,1600);');
```

But it doesn't work anymore.

There's no errors in console, so It's very difficult for debugging.

Actually, It works for me by another test case but I can't find differents between the scripts.

So I've tried to use *scrollIntoView* But I've got a kind og infinity loop.

**Full test case -**

```
describe('My business page ', function() {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var loginBox = element(by.css("div.info-box.client-login.ng-scope"));
    var centerElm = $$(("div.action-extra-content.wysiwyg-content.ng-binding.layout-column")).first();
    var scrollIntoView = function (element) {
      arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
    };

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });


  it('Main page - Top', function() {
    browser.get('https://live.vcita.com/site/bungee');
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loginBox), 30000);
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
  });

  it('Main page - Center', function() {
      browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, centerElm);
      console.log("Scroll me!!!")
      browser.driver.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(centerElm),30000);
      browser.driver.sleep(2000);
  });

});
```

**Error:**

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
   Stacktrace:
     RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.childCtor.base (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2163:38)
    at promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.constructor (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2431:23)
    at new wrappedCtr (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2366:26)
    at promise.Promise.addCallback_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:641:12)
    at promise.Promise.then (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:591:15)
    at Object.promise.asap (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:911:11)
    at C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:250:27
    at goog.object.forEach (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\object\object.js:35:7)
    at convertKeys (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:245:5)
    at convertValue (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:216:16)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\livesiteClient.js:26:3)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\livesiteClient.js:1:63)
```

Comment: have u tried using scrollintoview?

Comment: @noor  I've tried now and it receives an error about "RangeError: Maximum call stuck size exceeded"

Comment: give the full code how u use it with webelement

Comment: @noor Please see the main post above.

Comment: executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + element.getLocation().x + "," +(element.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");

Comment: try with this one.... so far i cant run ur code in my machine for some issue ... all suggestions are given based on my assumption.

Comment: It's not working as well, do you have any idea why? can you write me the exactly code I need to code? based on my code in the main post. thanks @noor

Comment: i think somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollable container is probably not the window/document. And to execute a script with a given element, you need to provide the native element returned by `.getWebElement()`:

```
var elm = $('...');
browser.executeScript(function(e){
    e.scrollIntoView();
}, elm.getWebElement());
```